# HTML Can't Find Table ID

Tags: java, html, mysql, eclipse, jsoup

http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/freeagency?leagueId=1566286&teamId=4&seasonId=2015#&seasonId=2015&view=projections&context=freeagency&avail=-1

I am trying to use JSoup to rip the table from this link. However I am very new to HTML and I can not find the right "table id" to use. My code is below, and I have gotten it to work for tables from other pages, so the code is not the issue. I just don't know how to find the right table id. Thank you!

This is the html code I see: http://pastebin.com/d5h5QBb6

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class readURL {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //extractTableUsingJsoup("http://mobilereviews.net/details-for-Motorola%20L7.htm","phone_details");
    extractTableUsingJsoup("http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/freeagency?leagueId=1566286&teamId=4&seasonId=2015#&seasonId=2015&view=projections&context=freeagency&avail=-1","INSERT TABLE ID HERE");
}

public static void extractTableUsingJsoup(String url, String tableId){
    Document doc;
    try {
        // need http protocol
        doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        //Set id of any table from any website and the below code will print the contents of the table.
        //Set the extracted data in appropriate data structures and use them for further processing
        Element table = doc.getElementById(tableId);

        Elements tds = table.getElementsByTag("td");

        //You can check for nesting of tds if such structure exists
        for (Element td : tds) {
            System.out.println("\n"+td.text());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

As output, which is not what I am looking for. I want the players and their projections.

this is the table i want to get

[image]

Comment: What call would I use to get the data from the table with the class name?

Comment: Please see my edits, the "maincontainertbl" doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: ohh i'm sorry i think we have to log in to it see the table you are talking about .

Comment: Added a picture so you can see the table!

Comment: Did that provide any new leads for what to use to access the data in the table?

Comment: hmm there is a problem .you may have to logged in to it before access the table .for example if i go to ur link what i see is http://i.imgur.com/VuoXF7m.png

Comment: I put the html code I see here: http://pastebin.com/d5h5QBb6

Comment: if you can find a link which will show the table even you are not logged in then you can easily access the table .you can check this by navigate to your url in private window of your browser .otherwise you have to log in to it throw jsoup

Comment: Is jsoup seeing the sane as you do in a regular browser ? try setting the useragent. Also, log the jsoup request to a file and examine.

Comment: So I have to log in somehow in order to see the correct html code?

Comment: @mpkostek yes .however the html code you posted doesn't have a table you looking for .

Comment: http://games.espn.go.com/ffl/tools/projections?slotCategoryId=0 I found this page, it is publicly available. It looks like it has the information I am looking for.

Comment: @mpkostek hmm yes you have find a better page.the table id is `playertable_0`